# Where do I manage TFS work item tags, such as rename or delete?

Tags: tfs

If a tag in TFS Update 2 is entered incorrectly and saved, how can it later be edited and corrected? Also is there a way to delete obsolete tags?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From [Add tags to work items to categorize and filter lists and boards](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/add-tags-to-work-items)

> ### Delete or remove tags
>
> You can't delete a tag itself. However, if you
>   delete a tag from all work items to which it's currently assigned, the
>   system will delete the tag. The system automatically deletes
>   unassigned tags after 3 days of disuse.
>
> If you misspell a tag, don't assign the misspelled tag to any work
>   item and the system will automatically delete it within 3 days.

Here are some other options:

[Tags Manager for VSTS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YodLabs.TagsManager2)

[Tag Admin for VS2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UtkarshShigihalliandTarunArora.TagAdminforVisualStudio2017)

[Other tag editor options for VSTS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=tags&target=VSTS&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance)

Comment: This isn't new for me but the question was how to delete/rename tags. The correct answer would be: There is no rename/delete feature but you can use the following workarounds: <your text/answer here>. Just imagine when you have 100 or more PBIs ... ;-)

Answer (score 10):

It is not possible to rename or delete tags in TFS at the moment.

Comment: This is simply a true/correct answer. Don't understand why there was votes -1 before (voted so that it is 0 now ;-) - maybe you should say no rename/delete feature, but there's a workaround)  Of course the other answer is also correct but in daily business where you have 100 PBIs or more that "rename approach" will use lot of effort ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Old question, but for anyone arriving here after googling (like I did at first) I'd like to mention that there is a Visual Studio extension available, which allows tag editing:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/057740ff-86be-4a44-b2bb-7e6d68b75455

You can rename and delete tags, plus a few other features!

The extension appears on the Team Explorer tab in Visual Studio. Here are a couple of screen shots from the 2017 version:

[image: Tag Admin screen shot 1]

[image: Tag Admin screen shot 2, tag selected]

Here is the link to the latest (2017) version:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UtkarshShigihalliandTarunArora.TagAdminforVisualStudio2017

Comment: @Baum, I'm not sure how I'd demonstrate that. It's an extension for Visual Studio, and it allows you to do what the OP asked for; e.g. renaming and deleting tags. But I already wrote that, of course. I guess I could add a screen shot, I'll see if I can do that, but other than that I'm not sure how to achieve what you ask for. Any hints?

Comment: Thanks, looks much better now. It is important that people can judge the quality of your answer without having to go to (potentially changing or disappearing) third party websites IMO. (Granted, I could probably have picked a better comment earlier.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Does not appear to (yet) be a version for Visual Studio 2017. Hopefully soon.

Comment: @joshmcode - oh but there is a version for 2017. The screenshots above are actually from VS2017, and the link below the screenshots is to the 2017 version of the plugin.

Comment: @Culme Great! Not sure how I missed that when looking around the Internet.

Comment: Nice tool! But way to slooooowww!